# Acess nested params in view form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I'm having trouble trying to upload images, I have a control that receives nested parameters from other models (availability, personal documents, etc ...), I made the relationships between the entities and added the "has_one_attached: img_name_example" in each model that must have an image, then I made a view with a form to be able to test the post of this form, but whenever I submit in the form I re-post the following message:

***{"status":"ERROR","errors":{"disponibility":["must exist"],"personal_document":["must exist"],"personal_document_legal":["must exist"],"bank_information":["must exist"]}}***

***Code:***

Client model:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    enum user_kind: { partner: "P", service_taker: "T" }

    belongs_to :disponibility
    belongs_to :personal_document
    belongs_to :personal_document_legal
    belongs_to :bank_information

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bank_information
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :disponibility
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_document
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_document_legal
end
```

Client controller (require and permit):

```
def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(
    :user_kind,
    disponibility_attributes: [
      :days, 
      :period
    ],

    personal_document_attributes: [
      :rg_front, 
      :rg_back, 
      :cpf, 
      :cnh_front, 
      :cnh_back, 
      :bank_card_front, 
      :address_proof, 
      :profile_picture
    ],

    personal_document_legal_attributes: [
      :cnpj, 
      :social_contract, 
      :bank_card_front
    ],

    bank_information_attributes: [
      :bank, 
      :account_type, 
      :agency, 
      :account_number
    ]
  )
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_with model: @client, local: true  do |form| %>

<%= form.text_field :user_kind %> <br>

<br>

<%= form.text_field :days %> <br>
<%= form.text_field :period %> <br>

<br>

  <%= form.file_field :rg_front %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :rg_back %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :cpf %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :cnh_front %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :cnh_back %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :bank_card_front %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :address_proof %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :profile_picture %><br>

  <br>

  <%= form.file_field :cnpj %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :social_contract %><br>
  <%= form.file_field :bank_card_front %><br>

  <br>

  <%= form.text_field :bank %> <br>
  <%= form.text_field :account_type %> <br>
  <%= form.text_field :agency %> <br>
  <%= form.text_field :account_number %> <br>

<br>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I check your previous question, I think this deal how you setup your relationship between
client and other tables, if you are sure that client hold only **One** personal_document then
you can set as follow, if you think client can hold more than one personal document then 
you have to change it to has_many

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  # please note personal_document in singular
  has_one :personal_document, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_document, allow_destroy: :true

  # now you can do some like above for disponibility, personal_document_legal, bank_information
end

class PersonalDocument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
end

class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def barang_params
    params.require(:client).permit(
      :user_kind,
      personal_document_attributes: [
        :id,
        :rg_front, 
        :rg_back, 
        :cpf, 
        :cnh_front, 
        :cnh_back, 
        :bank_card_front, 
        :address_proof, 
        :profile_picture
      ]
      # I think this one already correct
    )
  end
end
```

please note also since Client is parent and PersonalDocument is child
the one that relate this is field in personal_documents table that hold
client_id

check your schema here how you do migration

```
create_table "personal_documents", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "client_id"
  # .... your other fields
end
```